# UIPickerView for Multi UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I'm trying to have `UIPickerView` in each textfield that I have in one view. When I choose the value in the first textfield it forced the second textfield to show the same value.

I'm trying to have the different value for each.

```
@IBOutlet var gpaFieldOne: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var gpaFieldTwo: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var gpaResult: UILabel!

let picker = UIPickerView()
var grades = ["A","B","C","D","F"]

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
   return grades.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return grades[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    gpaFieldOne.text = grades[row]
    self.view.endEditing(false)
    gpaFieldTwo.text = grades[row]
    self.view.endEditing(false)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.dataSource = self
    gpaFieldOne.inputView = picker
    gpaFieldTwo.inputView = picker
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `didSelectRow` sets both text fields every time. You need to set the `text` of only the current text field, not both.

You need to make a few changes to track the current text field.

Start by adding a new property:

```
var currentTextField: UITextField?
```

Make sure you set the delegate of both text fields. Make the connection in your storyboard or set them in code (in `viewDidLoad`).

Implement the `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    currentTextField = textField
}
```

Now update your `didSelectRow` to the following:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if let currentTextField = currentTextField {
        currentTextField.text = grades[row]
        currentTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        self.currentTextField = nil
    }
}
```

Comment: it gives me an error and it says    "Cannot assign to value: 'currentTextField' is a 'let' constant"

Comment: the line that has problem is   currentTextField = nil .. so when I comment this line the app works perffect. However, I dont know what is the consequnces of commenting this line. Would you tell me the benefits of this line to I can have to use all the advantages of the code that you provide it for me ? .. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget about your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260876/how-to-call-function-from-another-swift-file). It needs to be deleted or properly updated.